# Executing a binary on an App Service Application

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, shell-exec

I want to migrate my PHP web app (which is on Azure Repos) from Azure VM to Azure Web App Service (python, not php though) + Azure SQL + Azure Storage + Azure Redis.

But there was a `shell_exec()` I was doing in my Azure VM in my PHP app when a specific button was clicked on the portal - now how do I execute this in Azure Web App Service ? This would not be possible since I can only push code to Web App Service by connecting to the Repos - and I don't think I can push an executable to the repo which will get executed on clicking on the button on the UI form ?

So what's the alternative ?

Creating a VM for this purpose alone defeats the purpose of migrating from VM to App Service.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom executable, you should be able to bundle it into the zip deployment package that you are doing.

But note that it might not that be that simple due to many reasons like OS architecture, windows vs linux, shared libraries, etc.

The better option would be to either [deploy a Custom Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container) to App Service or use [Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview).